# SELECT ... INTO fails for one variable, but not for two

Tags: mysql

Running a fairly old version of MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT @@version;
+-----------+
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 5.0.77    |
+-----------+
```

Afraid I'm not at liberty to update it, so I acknowledge the easy answer may be "Upgrade MySQL to a newer version."

When I do `SELECT...INTO` query which should return a single row with only one column I get an error:

```
mysql> SELECT id
  INTO @active_id
  FROM a_table
  WHERE active = 1
  LIMIT 1
  ;

> Undeclared variable: id
```

But if I add an additional column, it works fine:

```
mysql> SELECT id, 42
  INTO @active_id, @ignored
  FROM a_table
  WHERE active = 1
  LIMIT 1
  ;
> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @active_id, @ignored;

+------------+----------+
| @active_id | @ignored |
+------------+----------+
| 1          | 42       |
+------------+----------+
```

Is there a better workaround for this?  Is my syntax wrong somehow?

Comment: Why does the error refer to `request_id` when the example selects into `@active_id`?

Comment: out of curiosity what happens when you drop the into clause e.g. `SELECT id FROM a_table WHERE active = 1  LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Michael: Copy and paste error where I was making the simplest possible reproduction.  I updated the question as you were typing your comment.

Comment: @ConradFrix: As demonstrated by the two column version, it works fine, returning a single row.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I was curious if MySQL was having trouble with `SELECT id ` vs `SELECT id, 42` irrespective of the `INTO` clause, so I wasn't convinced that the two column version does, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @ConradFrix: FWIW, I had tried that as well to diagnose before posting, but since I need to use the value from the SELECT in later logic in a stored procedure, it's of no utility to me that a SELECT with no INTO doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Did you ever find the solution to this?  I'm having a semi-related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424844/why-am-i-getting-this-mysql-error-42s02-no-such-table-in-my-stored-procedure