# Why am I getting this MySQL Error 1146 (No Such Table) in my Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, exception, variables, stored-procedures

Here is my MySQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProc(DB_NAME varchar(30)) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE NO_EXAM_TABLE BOOLEAN;

    /*This one throws 'No Such Table' exception*/
    SELECT IF(count(*) = 0, TRUE, FALSE) 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS cols 
    WHERE cols.TABLE_SCHEMA = DB_NAME 
    AND cols.TABLE_NAME = 'exam' 
    INTO NO_EXAM_TABLE;

    /*But this one works fine (removed the INTO clause)*/
    SELECT IF(count(*) = 0, TRUE, FALSE) 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS cols 
    WHERE cols.TABLE_SCHEMA = DB_NAME 
    AND cols.TABLE_NAME = 'exam';
END;
```

Does MySQL think `NO_EXAM_TABLE` is a table instead of a variable?

**EDIT**

This is what I'm using to catch the error:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1146 BEGIN SELECT "42S02 (ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE) Table doesn't exist" as 'ERROR_NO SQLSTATE'; ROLLBACK; END;
```

**EDIT2**

I've narrowed the problem down to this clause:

```
AND cols.TABLE_NAME = 'exam';
```

If I change it to this, it works:

```
AND cols.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'exam';
```

I don't understand why the `=` operator is causing an error and the `LIKE` operator is working fine.

Comment: What is the **full** error message?

Comment: @Jocelyn I edited the question to show what I'm using to catch the error.  As you can see, the error message is just what I told it to be.  How can I find out which table it thinks is missing?

Comment: I read your question too fast yesterday, and I didn't notice you had declared an error handler.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the INTO in the correct position:

```
select ...
into var
from table
where ...
```

Comment: Actually, the INTO clause can be at the end as I have it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html